# how to configure formidable in app.use express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

this is a simple question... how can i use formidable instead bodyparser()...

how to configure in app.use

```
app.configure(function(){
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 9000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options',{layout:false});
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.bodyParser();
app.use(express.cookieParser('blocksecretpass'));
app.use(express.session());
```

im using expressjs 3 rc4 nodejs 0.8 formidable 1.0.11 on windows 7 64-bit
why i need?? because i have to post some files and bodyparser() shutdown my node app
this is the error

```
https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/34
https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/130
```

the solution to issues is app.use express.bodyparser before any other middleware that try to use async calls

tnx all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using formidable. Express is based on [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) and the [multipart](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html) middleware is based on formidable. Have a look at the [express example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/multipart/index.js) to learn how to upload files.

Comment: i know that... i dont want to use the multipart of coonect i want to deactivate multipart and use formidable instead

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `.bodyParser()`, it is being deprecated.

Use

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Consider using alternatives: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html. [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) is one of them.

Comment: The problem is these middlewares don't support file uploads

Comment: Yes, and that's why you need to plug in one, that does, manually. [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) is one of them.